# How to SQL select only most recent from related table

Tags: sql, mysql, mariadb, left-join, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table of requests from which I want to select everything, and I have a related table of positionReports where I want to select only the most recent report.

The below SQL does what I want as long as there is only one position report, but as soon as there are more, I understand that the SQL has no idéa which one I want. But I don't know how to specify that.

```
SELECT
r.id mission_id,
report.Timestamp as reportTimestamp,
report.Latitude as reportLat,
report.Longitude as reportLng,
FROM Requests r
LEFT JOIN PositionReports report ON r.id = report.RequestId
```

---------------- UPDATE -------------

Guided by this [MySQL JOIN the most recent row only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619030/mysql-join-the-most-recent-row-only) I managed to fetch the most recent one, but then a new problem is that I only get retrieved such missions that actually has position reports.

```
    WHERE report.Id = (
        SELECT MAX(Id)
        FROM PositionReports
        WHERE RequestId = r.Id
    )";
```

Is there a way to retrieve all such that don't have an entry in the Reports table as well? Tried outer joins but no difference...

It is a MySQL database (testing environment is MariaDB but production is MySQL (DigitalOcean).

When you suggest pre-aggregating, does that mean that what I aim to accomplish is not possible in 1 SQL query alone?

Sample data -----------------------

So let's say the RequestsTable contains two entries, id's 178 and 179.

| id | otherdata |
| --- | --- |
| 178 | lorem.... |
| 179 | ipsum.... |

Only one of these, 179, has matching rows in the positionReports table.

The PositionReports table contains

| id | requestId | Timestamp | Latitude | Longitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 179 | 123456700 | 56.5 | 11.9 |
| 1 | 179 | 123456789 | 57.0 | 12.0 |

Desired output (the query should retrieve both). Ideally pick the positionReport with the highest value in Timestamp, but sorting on Id would work too for this implementation as I force chronology in accepting the reports.

| requestId | Timestamp | Latitude | Longitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 178 |  |  |  |
| 179 | 123456789 | 57.0 | 12.0 |

Comment: You need to pre-aggregate or filter the rows before joining, probably in a lateral join, assuming your RDBMS supports it.

Comment: What determines 'most recent' - highest ID in PositionReports or latest date? Sample data and desired output as formatted text table(s) can be helpful. Most likely need a nested subquery.

Answer (score 1):

I think I made it at least work thanks to this [Return all data from 1st Table, and only 1 data from 2nd Table if exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47575573/return-all-data-from-1st-table-and-only-1-data-from-2nd-table-if-exist?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I'm not sure how efficient (or should I say resource-hogging) this solution is.

```
        SELECT
        r.id as id,
        reports.Timestamp as reportTimestamp,
        reports.Latitude as reportLat,
        reports.Longitude as reportLng,
        FROM Requests r
        LEFT JOIN 
        
        (SELECT 
          c.* 
        FROM
          PositionReports c 
          LEFT JOIN PositionReports d 
            ON c.RequestId = d.RequestId 
            AND c.Timestamp < d.Timestamp 
        WHERE d.RequestId IS NULL) reports
        
        ON r.id = reports.RequestId
```

Answer (score 1):

With no claims about resource consumption - an alternative approach, using the RANK window function:

```
SELECT
  r.id as id,
  reports.Timestamp as reportTimestamp,
  reports.Latitude as reportLat,
  reports.Longitude as reportLng
FROM RequestsTable r
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    *,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY RequestId ORDER BY Timestamp DESC) as rnk
  FROM PositionReports
  ) reports
  on reports.RequestId = r.id
  and reports.rnk = 1
;
```

See it in action: [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bnSzHsK4sJYBrgg8dm5gtp/0).

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to retrieve all such that don't have an entry in the Reports table as well?

The problem with your code is that you are using the `where` clause for filtering - so this evicts records that did not match in the `left join`. You can just move the filtering to the `on` clause of the join, as in:

```
select
    r.id mission_id,
    pr.Timestamp as reportTimestamp,
    pr.Latitude as reportLat,
    pr.Longitude as reportLng
from Requests r
left join PositionReports pr 
    on  pr.RequestId = r.id
    and pr.id = ( select max(pr1.id) from PositionReports pr1 where pr1.RequestId = r.Id)
```

Now we can see that the first join condition seems redondant, since the second condition covers it; this should be good enough:

```
select
    r.id mission_id,
    pr.Timestamp as reportTimestamp,
    pr.Latitude as reportLat,
    pr.Longitude as reportLng
from Requests r
left join PositionReports pr 
    on pr.id = ( select max(pr1.id) from PositionReports pr1 where pr1.RequestId = r.Id)
```

---

Finally: if you are running MySQL 8.0.13 or higher, this looks like a very good spot for a lateral join:

```
select r.id mission_id,
    pr.Timestamp as reportTimestamp,
    pr.Latitude as reportLat,
    pr.Longitude as reportLng
from Requests r
left join lateral (
    select pr.*
    from PositionReports pr 
    where pr.RequestId = r.Id
    order by id desc limit 1
) pr on 1
```

The subquery correlates with the outer query, and directly returns the record you are looking for; with an index on `PositionReports(RequestId, id desc)`, this should be an efficient solution.