# MySQL INNER JOIN Select only one row from other table

Tags: mysql

I have been trying to figure out a MySQL statement to perform the following.

- I have a table with that stores jobs (tbl_jobs).
- Another table that stores work scheduling (tbl_schedule) in the form of fixed time slots.
- I want the resulting query to show all jobs scheduled today, check if the jobs are already scheduled (timeslot field) and return the earliest time slot.
- My timeslots are stored as numbers from 1-8 so I used MIN to get the smallest number.

  - There can be the same job spanning multiple timeslots.

I tried a code from [MySQL INNER JOIN select only one row from second table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526194/mysql-inner-join-select-only-one-row-from-second-table) but I believe I don't understand the query in depth enough to make my own statement for my purposes

```
 SELECT a.*, c.*
      FROM tbl_jobs a
      INNER JOIN tbl_schedule c
      ON a.job_id =  c.job_id
           INNER JOIN (
           SELECT job_id, MIN(timeslot) ts
           FROM tbl_schedule 
           GROUP BY job_id
           ) b ON c.job_id = b.job_id
      WHERE date = '2018-01-05'
```

This query on returns jobs that are scheduled and the ones that are not scheduled do not show up at all.

Would appreciate if anyone can assist me in where I should go from here? I am at a roadblock so, I decided to post here for help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to use left join to get the unscheduled job

Answer (score 1):

To get unscheduled  job, use the left join

```
  SELECT a.*, c.*
  FROM tbl_jobs a
  LEFT JOIN tbl_schedule c
  ON a.job_id =  c.job_id
       LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT job_id, MIN(timeslot) ts
       FROM tbl_schedule 
       GROUP BY job_id AND
       ) b ON c.job_id = b.job_id
  WHERE date = '2018-01-05'
```