# MySQL INNER JOIN select only the first latest created row

Tags: mysql, subquery, inner-join

I've tried and searched all the day before post but I'm not able to figure out how to solve my problem.

I've a table essentially like this

```
ID | Name | RelatedTo | CreatedAt | Revision
```

Basically this track a document name with its content and if is which revision is (0,1,2,3,...) and if it's related to a "father" document (optional).

A document can have or not a revision

```
ID | Name | RelatedTo | CreatedAt | Revision
1  | A    |           | 2019-11-01| 0
2  | B    |           | 2019-11-01| 0
3  |      | 2         | 2019-11-04| 1
```

I was start from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526194/mysql-inner-join-select-only-one-row-from-second-table) but I'm not able to make it working for my case.

I need to select the master record (ex A and B) and the last CreatedAt field (2019-11-01 for A, 2019-11-04 for B).

Comment: how are the two A and B related i understand  3 goes to 2 but 2 goes not  to 1.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) and note that while minimal, 3 rows is rarely enough to be representative.

Comment: @nbk A document can have or not a revision B (2) have (3) A(1) doesn't have. AA and B are not related, are different document. Thanks

Comment: i added some more Lines to your example, i can see only a recursive loop in a stored procedure, you should have added the names and not used the relatedto column

Comment: @Hw.Master any comment on the answers ? Did any of them helped you ? Would be nice to give a feedback after the question is asken.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subquery for max date group by name

```
select m.* 
from  my_table m
inner join  (
  select  name, max(reatedAt) max_date
  from   (
    select  name, createdAt
    from my_table 
    union 
    select m1.name, m2.createdAt
    from my_table m1 
   inner join  my_table m2 ON m1.id = me.RelatedTo
  ) t
  group by name
)  t ON t.name  = m.name 
      and t.max_date  = m.CreatedAt
```

Comment: your example seem to return only one record, the document A

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

```
select a.RelatedTo
       , max(a.name)
       ,  max(a.m) 
from (select RelatedTo
             , name
             , max(CreatedAt) m 
      from my_table 
      where RelatedTo is not null
      group by RelatedTo
               , name
      union all
      select id
             , name
             , max(CreatedAt) m 
      from my_table 
      where RelatedTo is null
      group by ID
            , name ) a
group by a.RelatedTo
order by a.RelatedTo
```

Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dd101cfdd5484e9c840f4824dd98d12c)