# How can I get just one result? SQL: CASE Returns two rows

Tags: sql, oracle, case, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two tables for car information’s to identify which type of engine they have. Therefore I need a second table where all the special equipment of the car is listed. Table 1 distinguishes between Battery and No-Battery. With the key of the special equipment out of table2 it can be identified if the "No-Battery" Cars are Hybrids or Combustion Engine Cars. If they have the special Equipment "ABC" Key, they are Hybrid Cars. If not they are Combustion Cars.

**Table 1:**

```
> ID    |Car    |Engine      |
> 1     |RED    |BATTERY     |  
> 2     |YELLOW |NO-BATTERY  |
> 3     |BLUE   |NO-BATTERY  |
```

**Table 2:**

```
-ID-|SPECIAL EQUIPMENT
1   |AAA
1   |BBB
1   |CCC
2   |ABC
2   |BBB
2   |CCC
3   |ABC
3   |BBB
3   |CCC
```

**THE SQL Query is:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT    mytable.id, mytable.car, mytable.engine
FROM
    (SELECT table1.id, table1.car, table1.engine, table1.type,
    
    CASE    WHEN table1.type = 'Battery'    THEN 'BEV'
            WHEN table1.type = 'No-Battery'     THEN (CASE   WHEN special Equipment = 'ABC' THEN 'HYBRID' 
                                                      ELSE 'COMBUSTION' END)                                               
    END AS engine
    
    FROM table1
    INNER JOIN table 2 key ON table1.id = table2.id  
    WHERE (cars.id = 2 )  
)t;
```

The SQL Code Returns for CAR ID 2 --> 2 Columns, one time with engine type Hybrid and one time with engine type combustion.

RESULT (Current):

```
> ID    |Car    |type        |engine
> 2     |YELLOW |NO-BATTERY  |HYBRID    
> 2     |YELLOW |NO- BATTERY |COMBUSTION
```

I WANT TO SHOW:

```
> ID    |Car    |type        |engine
> 2     |YELLOW |NO-BATTERY  |HYBRID
```

The Result with Combustion is wrong but is displayed... how can i just get one right return?

Comment: May its the inner join? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526194/mysql-inner-join-select-only-one-row-from-second-table something in this direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want `exists`:

```
select t1.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from table2 t2
                          where t2.id = t1.id and t2.special = 'ABC'
                         )
             then 'Hybrid' else 'Combustion'
        end) as engine
from table1 t1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you are asking for

```
SELECT DISTINCT    mytable.id, mytable.car, mytable.engine
```

When you only want to show distinct mytable.car

In the results there are two different mytable.engine show it is showing you both as they are distinct.

```
SELECT DISTINCT    mytable.car
```

I do not know much about JQL